# Python 3: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6

I'm a new user of `Python`. I have recently changed from `Python 2.7 to Python 3.6` and I am having trouble with the one line of the code that worked before in `Python 2.7`. Please can someone help with the line below:

```
paidgrouped_large = paidgrouped.loc[paidgrouped['Gross Incurred Inf'].astype(int) > paidgrouped['Largeclaimcutoff'].astype(int), :].set_index('Claim', drop=True)
```

which now gives me the error:

> `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Both columns are just columns of numbers and there are no null data.
Does anyone have an idea why it's not working?